# What is "error C2061: syntax error : identifier "?

Tags: c++

When I compile there is an error call "error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Player' "

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. Here is my code

> ```
> #include "Platform.h"
> #include "Player.h"
> class Collision
> {
> public:
>   Collision(void);
>   ~Collision(void);
>   static bool IsCollision(Player &player, Platform& platform);
> };
> ```

There is an error in "IsCollision" method.

Player.h

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "rapidxml.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Collision.h"
using namespace rapidxml;
class Player
{
private:
    sf::Texture playerTexture;
    sf::Sprite playerSprite;
    sf::Vector2u position;
    sf::Vector2u source;
    sf::Vector2u size;
    int frameCounter, switchFrame, frameSpeed;
    int walkSpriteWidth;
    float velocity;
    bool isWalk;
    bool isStand;
    bool isFaceRight;

public:
    Player(void);
    ~Player(void);

    void Init();
    void Draw(sf::RenderWindow *window);
    void MoveForward();
    void MoveBackward();
    void Update(sf::Clock *clock);
    void SetSourceY(int value);
    void SetWalk(bool value);
    void SetFacing(std::string value);
    void SetStand(bool value);
    void Stand();
    std::string GetStatus();
    void PrintStatus();
    sf::Vector2f GetPosition();
    int GetWidth();
    int GetHeight();
};
```

Comment: SHow us your `Player.h`, please

Comment: Most probably, `Player` is in another namespace or even more probably - `Player.h` includes the header, containing this code.

Comment: @KirilKirov the latter seems more likely (given it's a very common mistake). You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @KirilKirov yup, the edit confirms that ;). If you do add an answer, mention include guards as well.

Comment: You have a circular include dependency. `Collision.h` includes `Player.h` and vice versa.

Comment: The problem is I include Collision.h in Player.h, Right ?

Comment: [Organizing Code Files in C and C++](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/organizing-code-files-in-c-and-c-r1798), Potential Pitfall 2

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have a circular include dependency. Collision.h includes Player.h and vice versa. The simplest solution is to remove `#include "Collision.h"` from `Player.h`, since the `Collision` class is not needed in the `Player` declaration. Besides that, it looks like some of your includes in `Collision.h` can be replaced by forward declarations:

```
// forward declarations
class Player;
class Platform;

class Collision
{
public:
  Collision(void);
  ~Collision(void);
  static bool IsCollision(Player &player, Platform& platform);
};
```

You can then put the includes in `Collision`'s implementation file.

Answer (score 8):

That's a pretty common mistake - you have circular include dependency.

Looking at your code, you should replace `#include "Player.h"` with `class Player;` in  `Collision.h`. This is called "forward declaration" and will break the circular dependency.

---

Also, it would be good to add include guards, for example:

```
#ifndef MY_PLAYER_CLASS
#define MY_PLAYER_CLASS

...

#endif
```

And this should be done for each header you write.

Answer (score 2):

Circular dependency or you're using a C compiler for C++ code

Comment: Your answer may be right but, You may need to use the comment section for short answers